# Variable has already been defind error when insert via for loop

Tags: c#

I'm having two mysql `TABLES` - `ORDER` and `ORDER_DETAILS` the relationship is one order has many order_details.

After creating an order, I get  the last inserted id and I need to insert order details with last inserted last order id via a for loop. But here it is showing a message

> @order_id has already been defined

when having more than one order details. If it is one order detail it works.

How can I defined this order id here? Is this a wrong way? Here is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
        MydbConnection db = new MydbConnection();
        MySqlConnection con = db.connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into orders (created) values(@localDate)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@localDate", localDate);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        long lastId = cmd.LastInsertedId;//Last inserted id

        for (int i = 0; i < listView3.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into order_details (order_id,product_id,qty) values(@order_id,@product_id,@qty)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_id", lastId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", listView3.Items[i].SubItems[1]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception es) {
        MessageBox.Show("Order not saved! "+es.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try creating a new command object inside the loop.

Comment: put this `cmd = new MySqlCommand();` inside the loop too.

Comment: I did it also..  :(

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` you adding one more parameters. When you call it twice or more with parameter with same name duplicated parameters appears.

When your `listView3.Items.Count` contains at least two elements, your code will add duplicated `@order_id`, `@product_id` and `@qty`.

You need either to recreate your `MySqlCommand cmd` on each iteration, or change value of parameters when they already added.

First approach is more error-prone. Al least because you will not use other data left from previous usage (`@localDate` parameter you adding before loop, that otherwise will be also passed to database).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listView3.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into order_details (order_id,product_id,qty) values(@order_id,@product_id,@qty)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_id", lastId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", 1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", listView3.Items[i].SubItems[1]);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this. It is very wasteful to create a new `MySqlCommand` instance for every loop iteration when the parameters can simply be re-used - there might be thousands of loop iterations and all those instances will have to wait for garbage collection!

Comment: @Xharlie It's all depends on particular task. If he need to create tons of request very often this approach would not be optimal. However if several requests made quite rarely then it's a question about parts of nanosecond. It not worth to speak about it. The simplicity and maintainability of the code would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep adding the same command parameters over and over. Instead, why not re-use them:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
        MydbConnection db = new MydbConnection();
        MySqlConnection con = db.connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into orders (created) values(@localDate)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@localDate", localDate);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        long lastId = cmd.LastInsertedId;//Last inserted id

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into order_details (order_id,product_id,qty) values(@order_id,@product_id,@qty)";
        MySqlCommandParameter orderIdParam, productIdParam, qtyParam;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView3.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                orderIdParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_id", lastId);
                productIdParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", 1);
                qtyParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", listView3.Items[i].SubItems[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                orderIdParam.Value = lastId;
                productIdParam.Value = 1;
                qtyParam.Value = listView3.Items[i].SubItems[1];
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception es) {
        MessageBox.Show("Order not saved! "+es.Message);
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't actually tested this code and probably have the wrong types and member names for `MySqlCommandParameter` and `MySqlCommandParameter.Value` but you should still get the idea.

It would probably be better coding practice to `Add` the parameters first (before entering the loop) and not have the `if` block in the loop instead of using `AddWithValue` for the first loop iteration. You could also think about `Clear`-ing the parameter collection on the command and calling `AddWithValue` every iteration. Ultimately, I think it is best to re-use the parameters, though - certainly preferable to creating a new instance of `MySqlCommand` every iteration - there might be thousands of iterations!

Comment: I don't know. Basically, it's whatever type is returned by `AddWithValue`, hence my note that the type name is probably wrong. It will look very similar to this, though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as hinted in the comments, you need a way to remove the parameters added in the previous iteration of the loop:

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

placed after cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() will do that for you.  But beware!  The SQL connection, and the SQL command, .NET base types implement IDisposable, and you should despose of them properly when you're done with them to avoid things like connection pool blocking.  I've recently had to rescue an old project from poorly managed disposables and a) it was a pain but b) the result was a much faster, more reliable app.  You might want to look in to that when you've solved your current problem.